How to find which charts that use specific data source?
Background
I'm trying to locate all the chart that use a specific data source, but I can't find how to do it.
Here's what I'm referring to:

For example, the first data source is being used by 2 charts, but I cannot click that "2 charts" words.
Current Workaround
I go through every page of dashboard to find which charts use that data source, which is very difficult and time-consuming.
Question
Is there any way to do this quicker?

If the number of charts shown as Used in report doesn't match the number of charts in your report then check for filters on your pages — these also count towards the total usage.
